# Checking each value with every values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a function that check if a source IP address is within the network range of a destination IP network that looks like this.

```
def check_ip_address(self, src_ip_address, dst_ip_address):
    src_ip = src_ip_address.split('/')[0]
    dst_ip = dst_ip_address.split('/')[0]
    if src_ip == dst_ip:
        return True
    if ipaddress.ip_address(src_ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(f'{dst_ip_address}'):
        return True

    return False
```

I have a large dictionary (around 200k data) that contains the device name as the key and a list of IP addresses as the value. Some sample below.

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'RSGSMG11700102': ['10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.112/29', '10.2.21.113/32', '10.2.21.114/32', '10.2.21.115/32', '10.2.21.118/32', ...],
'RSGKUDUS11007903': ['10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.112/29', '10.2.21.118/32', '10.2.21.120/29', '10.2.21.126/32', '10.2.21.128/29', ...],
'RSGJGY12700103': ['2.2.2.2/32', '10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.160/29', '10.2.21.161/32', '10.2.21.162/32', '10.2.21.163/32', '10.2.21.166/32', ...],
'RSGJGY12700104': ['2.2.2.2/32', '10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.160/29', '10.2.21.161/32', '10.2.21.162/32', '10.2.21.163/32', ...]}
```

I wanted to check if the IP address exist in other devices (match IP and match network) using the function above. Each IP address of every devices will need to go through the checking.

The result should display twice for A vs B matched value and B vs A matched value.

For example 10.0.22.16/29 of RSGSMG11700102 exist in RSGKUDUS11007903 and 10.0.22.16/29 of RSGKUDUS11007903 exist in RSGSMG11700102.

Each device consist of 1500 IP addresses and I have more than 140 devices to loop for. Using nested loop to run this took forever to complete, is there any faster or more efficient way to generate the result?

Comment: You can use `multiprocessing`

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example? What is `ipaddress.ip_address` and `ipaddress.ip_network`?

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu Yes, using multiprocessing is what I will go for after that. Just wanted to know if there is any other faster way using built-in functions or any libraries that will even further more help in improving the efficiency

Comment: Since those values seem to be mostly duplicates, you can probably slap a `@functools.lru_cache()` on the `check_ip_address` function (which should be a free function, not a method, since it doesn't use `self`) for a good boost.

Comment: @BeChillerToo these are the functions in the ipaddress library https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Comment: I don't know if the `if` statements slows the operation or not. But it looks like simply returning `src_ip == dst_ip or ipaddress.ip_address(src_ip) in ipaddress.ip_network(f'{dst_ip_address}')` will do the job. And you can get rid of `if`s.

Comment: I don't have the time right now, but you should: 1) use `ipaddress.overlaps` to see if 2 networks overlap, 2) You should not perform the same computations at every iterations: you compute the `split` everytime you compare 2 addresses, you could do it just once. and 3) You don't have to iterate over all combinations of addresses, if you compare N1 and N2, you already know if N2 and N1 overlap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a first solution:

```
import ipaddress
import itertools
# I changed the devices names to something more simple
data = {'R102': ['10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.112/29', '10.2.21.113/32', '10.2.21.114/32', '10.2.21.115/32', '10.2.21.118/32'],
        'R903': ['10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.112/29', '10.2.21.118/32', '10.2.21.120/29', '10.2.21.126/32', '10.2.21.128/29'],
        'R103': ['2.2.2.2/32', '10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.160/29', '10.2.21.161/32', '10.2.21.162/32', '10.2.21.163/32', '10.2.21.166/32'],
        'R104': ['2.2.2.2/32', '10.0.22.16/29', '10.2.21.160/29', '10.2.21.161/32', '10.2.21.162/32', '10.2.21.163/32']}


networks = {key: [ipaddress.IPv4Network(addr) for addr in addresses] for (
    key, addresses) in data.items()}

keys = list(networks.keys())

print(keys)

overlaps = []
for d1, d2 in itertools.combinations(keys, 2):
    for n1, n2 in itertools.product(networks[d1], networks[d2]):
        if n1.overlaps(n2):
            print("{} of {} overlaps {} of {}".format(n1, d1, n2, d2))
            overlaps.append((n1, d1, n2, d2))

print(overlaps)
```

This displays:

```
10.0.22.16/29 of R102 overlaps 10.0.22.16/29 of R903  
10.2.21.112/29 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.112/29 of R903
10.2.21.112/29 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.118/32 of R903
10.2.21.113/32 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.112/29 of R903
10.2.21.114/32 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.112/29 of R903
10.2.21.115/32 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.112/29 of R903
10.2.21.118/32 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.112/29 of R903
10.2.21.118/32 of R102 overlaps 10.2.21.118/32 of R903
10.0.22.16/29 of R102 overlaps 10.0.22.16/29 of R103  
10.0.22.16/29 of R102 overlaps 10.0.22.16/29 of R104  
10.0.22.16/29 of R903 overlaps 10.0.22.16/29 of R103  
10.0.22.16/29 of R903 overlaps 10.0.22.16/29 of R104
2.2.2.2/32 of R103 overlaps 2.2.2.2/32 of R104
10.0.22.16/29 of R103 overlaps 10.0.22.16/29 of R104
10.2.21.160/29 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.160/29 of R104
10.2.21.160/29 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.161/32 of R104
10.2.21.160/29 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.162/32 of R104
10.2.21.160/29 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.163/32 of R104
10.2.21.161/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.160/29 of R104
10.2.21.161/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.161/32 of R104
10.2.21.162/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.160/29 of R104
10.2.21.162/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.162/32 of R104
10.2.21.163/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.160/29 of R104
10.2.21.163/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.163/32 of R104
10.2.21.166/32 of R103 overlaps 10.2.21.160/29 of R104
```

And the list `overlaps` contains:

```
[
    (IPv4Network('10.0.22.16/29'), 'R102', IPv4Network('10.0.22.16/29'), 'R903'),
    (IPv4Network('10.2.21.112/29'), 'R102', IPv4Network('10.2.21.112/29'), 'R903'),
    (IPv4Network('10.2.21.112/29'), 'R102', IPv4Network('10.2.21.118/32'), 'R903'), 
    ..., 
    (IPv4Network('10.2.21.163/32'), 'R103', IPv4Network('10.2.21.163/32'), 'R104'),
    (IPv4Network('10.2.21.166/32'), 'R103', IPv4Network('10.2.21.160/29'), 'R104')
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, the overlaps method is really useful.